# How i can len a list from a .txt archive

Tags: python, list

```
followers = ["pedro", "pablo", "Juan", "Luis"]
print(followers)
with open('data.txt', 'w') as temp_op:
    temp_op.write('%s\n' % followers)
```

but now I need to know how to read that list and print this same

Comment: Consider reading on basic file handling in python through a simple Google search

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you really want to do but I think I could help you by providing these lines of code.

If you want to save each follower line by line into a file, you could use :

```
followers = ["pedro", "pablo", "Juan", "Luis"]
print(followers)

with open('data.txt', 'w+') as temp_op:
    for each in followers:
        temp_op.write(each+'\n')
```

If you want to print each follower as specified in the list, you could use:

```
followers = ["pedro", "pablo", "Juan", "Luis"]
for each in followers:
    print(each)
```

If you just want to get length of the list, you could use:

```
followers = ["pedro", "pablo", "Juan", "Luis"]
print(len(followers))
```

Welcome in our community by the way.

Comment: sorry I think I did not understand. What I was referring to is that I want to read a list (its content and its length) from a separate file (.txt) to be able to write it to the console. And the code that I posted I don't even know why I put it XD
and I'm sorry if I don't make myself understood, I don't speak English very well

Comment: Hi, no problem, if you have some issues to express what you have in mind in another language, you could use this site to convert it in English: https://www.deepl.com/translator
My natural language is French, so don't worry I understand what you mean.